# popPageした際に呼び出し元の画面で処理を行う方法

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui

こんにちは

Onsen-UIを使用して下記のようにページをプッシュしています。

```
myNavigator.pushPage("add.html", options);
```

またプッシュされたページで以下のようにpopPageで画面を終了していますが、この時に呼び出し元の画面で処理を行うにはどうしたらいいですか？

```
myNavigator.popPage();
```

どなたか方法をご存知の方はリンクなどでも良いのでご教授ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OnsenUIのドキュメント](http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#Navigationevents)は見ましたでしょうか？
OnsenUIのイベントの中に`postpop`というものがありますのでソレにバインドしましょう

```
ons.ready(function() {
  myNavigator.on('postpop', function(event) {
  });
});
```